# Blocking all ip except mine block some curl request

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to block a maximum of connection to my server as it needs to be accessible only from me and a website.
Then I added that to iptables:

```
*filter

-A INPUT -s my.own.ip/32 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s the.other.site.ip/32 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -j ACCEPT
-P INPUT DROP

COMMIT
```

But curl (through php) is no more able to access some urls.
What's wrong with that rules ?

EDIT: I think what I was missing is that I had to allow established connection traffic too like that:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: The proper loopback address is `127.0.0.0/8`

Comment: Add `-A INPUT -j LOG` so everything goes to log before being dropped.

Comment: Did you know that "php" can be seen as "that.other.ip" when *you* connect to it, but a totally different IP when *it connects* back to you? You need to verify that.

Answer (score 0):

> But curl (through php) is no more able to access some urls

Your rules are dropping all incoming that traffic that **isn't** `my.own.ip` or `the.other.site.ip`. So yes, if you are expecting to have PHP connect to something that is not these two IP's, you won't get very far. You will have to add specific statements for each IP that you want allowed.

Comment: Or maybe allow all outbound ?

Comment: Given that you've only added rules to the INPUT table, then it stands to assume that the OUTBOUND table is empty; an empty table means nothing is dropped, therefor you already have an allow all outbound. But if you're blocking INPUT based on source-ip, then if the source IP is NOT one of the configured ones in your list, it's getting dropped.

Comment: For me if I block only inbound, then outbound must work so curl must also, this is what I don't understand, can't I tell that connection initiated from server will work ?

Comment: TCP connections are two-way connections. You can't block only input and expect output to work as well. If you send a packet to 1.2.3.4, then 1.2.3.4 is going to send a response. If you allow outbound, that means the packet to 1.2.3.4 will leave your system, but if you're blocking everything inbound, then when 1.2.3.4 sends it's response, it's getting dropped since it's not in the allowed list.

Comment: You might want to look at some basic concepts of how a firewall operates. You've indicated a lack of knowledge in this category: https://computer.howstuffworks.com/firewall1.htm

Comment: And there's no way to tell iptables to add rules for incoming connections from outgoing connections ?

Comment: There is, they're called "related".